# Why does this scrolling code break when close to the bottom of the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I have this code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

    let chatElem = document.querySelector(".conversations-chat");

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      let diff = this.screenHeight - window.innerHeight;

      chatElem.scrollTop += diff;

      this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;      
    });
  }
```

Its purpose is so that when the virtual keyboard opens on mobile (which causes the resize event to trigger), then the scroll position is changed such that the user can still see the bottom-most message they were originally looking at.

This code works perfectly in the cases that the `conversations-chat` is long enough and the user is scrolled up enough. That is, opening the onscreen keyboard will and then closing it will keep the bottom-most visible message at the bottom of their screen.

The only issue is when closing the virtual keyboard when near the bottom of `conversations-chat`. For some inexplicable reason, this causes it to scroll to a fixed point from the bottom (from eyeballling it, it seems to be around the height of the virtual keyboard itself)

That is, if you are currently at the second-to-last message, and then you open the virtual keyboard and then close it, it will scroll to the tenth-to-last message. Any message between the tenth-to-last and last will always scroll to the tenth-to-last. It's only when you pass that arbitrary barrier does this code always work.

So I suppose there needs to be an additional logic check of something like `if (diff < 0 && nearTheBottom) { scrollMore(); }`, but I'm not sure why this is happening or even how to account for that or how much to scroll by.

I think if I even knew why this was happening to begin with, then maybe I could figure it out. It seems like such a strange issue where it only occurs if near the bottom.

Comment: As a note, you should generally avoid DOM queries on elements managed/rendered by react. Rather than use `document.querySelector`, consider using a `ref` to `chatElem` instead: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. This was just demonstration code. I can change it to a ref later. The issue still persists with refs.